# log4j jdbcappender for SqlServer

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, log4j

Is it possible to use the log4j JdbcAppender to log to MS SqlServer? If so, what are the settings I need for the URL and Driver params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any experience with JDBCAppender, but this [sample configuration](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/JDBCAppenderConfiguration) page seems pretty straightforward.

Here [is an MSDN article on building JDBC connection URLs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428%28v=sql.90%29.aspx). Driver name will be something like:

> com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver

**Edit:** [Here's](http://www.wowza.com/forums/showthread.php?6037-Logging-to-a-Database/page2) a post on appender setup if you need a sample.

Comment: Thanks for that. Rooting around in the documentation, it's not easy at all, it needs all kind of drivers and classpath config. So I mightstick with a file appender.